# Calling C++ member function from C

Tags: c++, c

Following is my C++ code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
extern "C" void wrapper(struct NB*, int );

struct AssetDbFilter {
    std::string attribute;
    std::string value;
  };

class NB {

public:
    void myTest(int a);
};
```

Following is C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
 #include "test.h"
using namespace std;

void NB :: myTest (int a) {

cout << a;
}
void wrapper(NB* nb, int a) {
nb->myTest(a);
}
```

Following is my c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "test.h"
void wrapper(struct NB* ,int );
int main()
{
    AssetDbFilter* assetdb;
    struct NB* nb;
    wrapper(nb, 5);
}
```

I am not able to execute this code.
I am calling C++ member function from a C code. When I execute this C file as `g++ test.c` I am getting following error:

```
/tmp/ccr1IaLa.o: In function `main':
test1.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `wrapper'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone tell me how can I resolve this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186743/discussion-on-question-by-sagar-deshpande-calling-c-member-function-from-c).

Answer (score 4):

You built `test.c`, great! Now you need to build the C++ file as well so that definitions are present.

Currently your toolchain thinks you want to compile *and link* `test.c` into an application, but `test.c` isn't your whole source code.

You can compile `test.c` without linking:

```
gcc test.c -c
```

Then do the same with your C++ file:

```
g++ whatever.cpp -c
```

Then link them together to get an executable:

```
g++ test.o whatever.o -o myProgram
```

Unfortunately your program will still not work because you are invoking a member function on a dangling/uninitialised pointer. Since you cannot instantiate an `NB` from your C code, this approach can't work.

I recommend `NB` contain only C-compatible members. Then you can put its definition into a shared header file and instantiate it whereever you please.

Comment: ... or just delegate object creation to C++: `extern "C" struct NB* createNB() { return new NB(); }`

Comment: IMHO it's worth of noting, for the sake of completness, that in pure c++ producing object files for external-linking is technically counterproductive, because there is name mangling and (I think) argument passing mode which are not standardized, so finding and using compiled functions is fragile. Keywords *C++ ABI*, *external and internal linkage*. The counter measure is of course to specify C-linkage, which c++-compliant compiler should provide and has its own implications.

Comment: @rustyx in which case be careful to also provide `freeNB` or similarly named function and document it in immediate vicinity of `createNB`, lest a C user of the API becomes confused about how to deal with the memory.